# How to check a HashMap for unique variables?

Tags: java

I have written code to find unique variables in a HashMap but it doesn't appear to work? I would like to be able to print the frequencies of each sausage type.

```
    if(sausagesEaten.isEmpty()) { //if the HashMap is empty
        System.out.println("No sausages have been eaten");
        System.out.println("======================================================="); ; 
    }
    else{
        HashMap<ArrayList, String> sausagesEaten = new HashMap<ArrayList, String>();
        for (String key : sausagesEaten) {
              System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(saustype, key));
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for here.  What is the meaning of the `ArrayList` key type?  What is `saustype`?  Are you trying to iterate through the values of the `HashMap`, the keys, or what?

Comment: your key is a list. you got your hashmap the other way around

Comment: In a word yes, the arrarylist is a list of sausage types such as beef, chicken etc

Comment: The key is meant to be a list of sausage types?

Comment: And of course `sausagesEaten` (the one you declare just before the loop) is empty when you try to iterate over it.

Comment: Tell us what information you want to store in the hashmap. something like: for each kind of sausage, a list of sausages of this kind that have been eaten.

Comment: I want to be able to store Sausage types alongside the amount of each sausage that has been eaten, this is why i have usen the collections.frequency method

Comment: So you should have a `List<SausageType>`, and call frequency on this list, or you should store the frequency of each type in a `Map<SausageType, Integer>`.

Comment: you are aware that a key cannot be altered after being added to a map. I suspect you should be using a set instead of a list unless the order matters or you can have duplicates in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already got a populated HashMap named sausagesEaten higher up in your code.

Change:

```
 if(sausagesEaten.isEmpty()) { //if the HashMap is empty
    System.out.println("No sausages have been eaten");
    System.out.println("======================================================="); ; 
}
else{
    HashMap<ArrayList, String> sausagesEaten = new HashMap<ArrayList, String>();
    for (String key : sausagesEaten) {
          System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(saustype, key));
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

To:

```
 if(sausagesEaten.isEmpty()) { //if the HashMap is empty
    System.out.println("No sausages have been eaten");
    System.out.println("======================================================="); ; 
}
else{
    for (String key : sausagesEaten) {
          System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(saustype, key));
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

By re-declaring the variable it is local scope and automatically empty.

Edit: Added change for proper iteration.

```
Iterator it = sausagesEaten.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error message "for-each not applicable to expression type. Required: Array or java.lang.iterable; found; java.util.HashMap<java.util.ArrayList, Java.lang.String>"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate directly over a `HashMap`.  Here's what you *can* do:

```
Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>(); // whatever K and V are

for (K key : map.keySet())
{
    // iterates over all the keys in random order
}

for (V value : map.values())
{
    // iterates over all the values, in random order
}
```

Also, it's very unorthodox and dangerous to use a mutable object such as an `ArrayList` as the key of a map, as in

```
HashMap<ArrayList, String> sausagesEaten = new HashMap<ArrayList, String>();
```

After you put it into the map, if you modify its contents in any way you will break the map and may or may not be able to retrieve it. I think you meant

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList> sausagesEaten = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
```

Also, in your code you re-declare `sausagesEaten` within the `else` clause, hiding the member variable of the same name.